# Android lottie animation not animating correctly

Tags: android, lottie

My animation works fine in the lottie preview as shown:
https://www.lottiefiles.com/share/6khKu9

However, when i run it on my android device it shows like the following:
https://gyazo.com/c757844fd29a51189413e3c059745119

I have created a simple animation manipulating a circle which works fine on my device.

My json file https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9571ykol75wnq7/test.json?dl=0

Comment: try enabling hardware accelerator https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel

Comment: @AkshayKatariya didn't work

Comment: There is issue with the animation path. If possible recreate it using adobe after effects and use plugin to generate JSON file. An alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled bodymovin and the problem is no more!